# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' from servlet

Tags: mysql, servlets, mysql-workbench

I am working on a mysql database, accessing from a Servlet program(through Eclipse) on Mac. My recent problem is, I couldn't access the mysql DB through my Servlet, which was working fine earlier. I use MySQLWorkBench, where the DB is running on Mac.
When Servlet is trying to access it, it throws the below error. Actually, the password is empty. Working on Mac machine.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Servlet code is below:

```
// MySQL
    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "root");        
    connectionProps.put("password", ""); // No password is set

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                       "jdbc:" + "mysql" + "://" +
                       "localhost" +
                       ":" + "3306" + "/InfoDB",
                       connectionProps);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    // insert record
    try {
        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT IP FROM InfoTable";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        String ipaddress = null;
          while(rs.next()){
              //Retrieve by column name
              ipaddress  = rs.getString("IP");
              System.out.println("IP Address retrieved from DB: " + ipaddress);
          }
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println(ipaddress);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The same code was working fine earlier. I saw some suggestions here, 
[***Solution for this issue***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908273/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) , 
but i don't know where is this `information.schema table` resides and how to set the permission.
And, another suggestion is there in this link, [***Solution for this issue***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972095/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password) But, i don't understand how to fix this way?

Could someone please guide me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `root` account don't have a password. So, make a connection with no password.

```
connectionProps.put("user", "root");        
// Remove this line --> connectionProps.put("password", ""); // No password is set
```

Or update the password of `root` account and connect using that password.

MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
```

Then

```
connectionProps.put("user", "root");        
connectionProps.put("password", "your-password");
```

Comment: Removing the line didn't solved the issue. Where I can apply "GRANT" command? I am running Mysqlworkbench on Mac machine.

Comment: @Catherine Just open a new query in MySQL Workbench and execute that command.

Comment: Or try this for empty password:
    `String password = "";
    //...
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,
                "root", password);`

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this one in another thread, copying from there.

I had similar problem and tried for hours to find the solution. Finally, I was able to solve the issue by updating the mysql-connector version. Try the latest connector version (5.1.29) and let me know if his works for you. This might help if you have updated your MySQL server version.

Answer (score 0):

i`m a student from Midrand Graduate Institute,South Africa this my error i corrected by changing the password phrase in double quotes to blank mysqlbench saves the password automatically.

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books",
                "root", "password");
changed it to:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books",
                "root", "");

And : my output
Listing all Books:
Book - Id: 1, Book Title: Practical Clojure
Book - Id: 2, Book Title: Beginning Groovy, Grails and
Griffon
Book - Id: 3, Book Title: Definitive Guide to Grails 2
Book - Id: 4, Book Title: Groovy and Grails Recipes
Book - Id: 5, Book Title: Modern Java Web Development
Book - Id: 6, Book Title: Java 7 Recipes
Book - Id: 7, Book Title: Java EE 7 Recipes
Book - Id: 8, Book Title: Beginning Java 7 
Book - Id: 9, Book Title: Pro Java 7 NIO.2
Book - Id: 10, Book Title: Java 7 for Absolute Beginners
Book - Id: 11, Book Title: Oracle Certified Java Enterprise
Architect Java EE7
Book - Id: 12, Book Title: Beginning Scala
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Searching Books by Keyword: Java
Book - Id: 5, Book Title: Modern Java Web Development
Book - Id: 6, Book Title: Java 7 Recipes
Book - Id: 7, Book Title: Java EE 7 Recipes
Book - Id: 8, Book Title: Beginning Java 7 
Book - Id: 9, Book Title: Pro Java 7 NIO.2
Book - Id: 10, Book Title: Java 7 for Absolute Beginners
Book - Id: 11, Book Title: Oracle Certified Java Enterprise
Architect Java EE7